# Magento - use attribute value as static block identifier

Tags: php, magento, attributes

Hi i am trying to use attribute value as a static block identifier. 
i have an attribute called `designer`. In my tabs on product page i want to display a static block depending on the value of this attribute

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('**designer**')->toHtml();
```

so i would like designer to be substituted with the value for the specific product, so if i have a product where the attribute value is `designer-1` i would like it to be

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('designer-1')->toHtml();
```

and so forth

Answer (score 0):

If you are outputting this in your template (while viewing product page ): Try below:

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$attributeText = $product->getAttributeText('designer');

//For uniformity of block identifiers, make it all lower case and make sure you are using lower case as block name
$lowerCaseValueForBlockId = strtolower($attributeText);

$cmsBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($lowerCaseValueForBlockId);
if ($cmsBlock->getId()) {
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($lowerCaseValueForBlockId)->toHtml();
    //Or you can use below code
    echo $cmsBlock->getContent();
}
```